# Asana API: Invalid Request when using task/addTag or creating a task with tags

Tags: php, api, asana, asana-api

I can't seem to be able to add tags to new or existing tasks.

I'm using the API from github at https://github.com/Asana/php-asana

Per the docs [here](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#tags), I set up the options and fired up the API call to the task endpoint. It fails with:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Asana\Errors\InvalidRequestError' with message 'Invalid Request' in /mydir/asana/Asana/Errors/AsanaError.php:29

```
    // create new task
    $newTaskOptions = array(
        'name' => $taskName,
        'notes' => $taskNotes,
        'projects' => [11111111115445],
        'tags' => [11111119991, 11111119992]   // without this, the task is created ok
    );

    $newTask = $client->tasks->create($newTaskOptions);
```

Here is the object that is sent to the `request` procedure:

```
array(2) {
  ["headers"]=> array(1) {
    ["content-type"] => string(16) "application/json"
  }
  ["data"]=> array(2) {
    ["data"]=> array(4) {
      ["name"]=> string(17) "module 1 - task 1"
      ["notes"]=> string(32) "description of module 1 - task 1"
      ["projects"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> int(11111111115445)
      }
      ["tags"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> int(11111119991)
        [1]=> int(11111119992)
      }
    }
    ["options"]=> array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Even with their example of `[ { id: 59746, name: 'Grade A' }, ... ]` (using the correct tag ids and names), it still errors out. Actually, it throws a syntax error at the first "{".

Next, if I try `tasks/taskid/addTag` to an existing task, I receive a similar error. Here's this piece of code below.

```
foreach ($tags as $tag){
  $newTag = $client->tasks->addTag($newTask->id, array('tag' => $tag));
}
```

The second part of the `addTag` command requires an array, and according to the documentation uses the `tag` as the array key. I tried other keys such as `text` or `data` or `tags` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue....tags are assigned to a workspace. So the tags being copied from workspace-1/project-1/task-1 to **workspace-2**/project-1/task-1 would not work UNLESS the tag was first created  in workspace-2.

Once the tag had been created in the destination workspace, the code worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at reproducing your first example and it totally worked for me. (Unfortunately, our API is asymmetric in some places, here's one of them: sending the array of IDs is the way to go, as presented in your very first example, but what you'll get back is those nested `{ID, name}` pairs in the response.)

I'm not sure what you might be running into - I suspect it's probably something outside of the actual PHP code you're using. I was able to get an invalid request error to throw if the IDs of the tags don't exist in Asana, could this be the problem?

To troubleshoot errors, we send back what we hope is a fairly friendly message in the response. If you change your request code above to

```
try {
  $newTask = $client->tasks->create($newTaskOptions);
} catch (Asana\Errors\InvalidRequestError $e) {
  var_dump($e->response->body);
}
```

hopefully it will help you see what's going on (i.e. in my repro, I got)

```
object(stdClass)#24 (1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(40) "tags: [1]: Unknown object: 1980346754317"
      ["help"]=>
        string(155) "For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue....tags are assigned to a workspace. So the tags I was copying from workspace-1/project-1/task-1 to **workspace-2**/project-1/task-1 would not work UNLESS I first created the tag in workspace-2.